# Responsive web design is working on desktop but not on the mobile device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The responsive design works in inspect elements emulator, but on a mobile device, it doesn't show the desired output.

**The HTML:**

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Esmaeeil enani</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="CVStyle.css" />
    <!--Online Font Awesome Call-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>
```

**The CSS:**

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1290px) {
    .skills .skill-item {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

}
```

There is more to the code, but this is the simplified version.

this how it looks on the desktop (inspect mode)
[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9TsH.png) [Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CL3b.png)

this how it looks on a mobile device (iPhone)
[on iPhone pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uotBM.jpg) [on iPhone pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8riy4.jpg)

It looks bad only on iPhone devices

Comment: Please show the output you are getting as well

Comment: Try updating your question with more information.

Comment: According to your pictures, there isn't a problem with the code you have provided. You'll have to figure out what's causing elements to clash. Probably the use of too many `display: fixed` or something similar in CSS. Posting all of your code on SO will only lead to more downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `.grid` css rule.

You need to change `height:100%` to `min-height:100%`

Comment: @Esmaeeilenani don't just add `min-height: 100%;` through media rules, you need to undo the `height`. So set it to `height:auto;` in that same rule.